# How to pull down large tbody from html using beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I was trying to pull down a tbody from https://iextrading.com/trading/market-data/#hist-download and couldn't bring down the contents with the body. Whenever I tried to pull down the table I got an empty

```
<tbody id="hist-rows">
</tbody>
```

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
BaseDataUrl = r"https://iextrading.com/trading/market-data"
base_download = r"https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/iex/o/data%2Ffeeds%2F"
BaseData = requests.get(BaseDataUrl)

soup = BeautifulSoup(BaseData.content, 'lxml')
tableofcontents = soup.find('div', class_="overflow-x-auto mb2")
tableofdownloads = soup.find('tbody', id="hist-rows")
tableofcontents = tableofcontents.findAll("th")

print(tableofdownloads)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On analyzing the website, the website makes an `ajax` call the get the data for the table. Hence, call the API to get the data. I have added the screenshots

[image]

[image]

The following code will get you the data

```
import requests

res = requests.get("https://iextrading.com/api/1.0/hist")

print(res.json())
```